# Showing that $f(a)=f'(a) = 0$ if and only if $f = (x-a)^2q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This was problem that I just cannot figure out:

Let $F$ be a field, $a\in F$ and $f\in F[x]$.  Show that $f(a)=f'(a)=0$ if and only if $f=(x-a)^2q$ for some $q\in F[x]$.  And $f'$ refers to the derivative of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

The if part is obvious.

For the only if part, since $f(a)=0$, there exist $g\in F[x]$ with $f=(x-a)g$. Now, $f'(x)=g(x)+(x-a)g'(x)$. So, $f'(a)=0$ implies $g(a)=0$. Thus again there exist $q \in F[x]$ with $g(x)=(x-a)q(x)$. Therefore, $f=(x-a)^2q$.

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason I am struggling with the obvious part as well.

Comment: well, if $f=(x-a)^2q$, then $f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)=(a-a)^2g'(a)+2(a-a)g(a)=0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Wlog, by a shift, assume the root is $\rm\: a = 0.$

Notice $\rm\ \ x^2\: |\ f(x)$

$\rm\ \iff\ x\ |\ f(x)\ $ and $\rm\ x\ \bigg|\ \dfrac{f(x)}{x}$

$\rm\ \iff\ f(0) = 0\ $ and $\rm\ x\ \bigg|\ \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}x\iff \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}x\bigg|_{\:x\:=\:0} =\: 0$

$\rm\ \iff\ f(0) = 0\ $ and $\rm\ f'(0) = 0$